# CSS: Intersect 2 div with 2 different classes & different margins applied - Anomaly or expected behavior?

Tags: css

What I want to understand:

1. Margin merge (margin bottom of div 1 with margin top of div2) if have the same value when 2 different div intersect? It seems so!
2. Padding do not merge (margin bottom of div 1 with margin top of div2) if is the same value when 2 different div intersect? It seems so!
3. When 2 different div with different padding intersect each div will respect his padding, so, basically height / distance between them will be more higher than like using margins (because padding do not merge)? It seems so!

**Question:** When 2 different div with 2 different classes intersect (margin bottom of div 1 with margin top of div2), the div with higher margin value will use previous div margin (calculate margin height from previous div and will add only the difference)? This is the expected behavior?

Does anyone know a tool to measure / show visual the distance in PX between 2 objects on browser (div / images / paragraph etc). Some Firefox / Chrome add-ons?

```css
.div1-margin {
margin: 32px 0;
background-color: #fcfcc0;
}
.div2-margin {
margin-top: 132px;
background-color: #c0fcf9;
}
.div1-padding {
padding: 32px 0;
background-color: #c5fcc0;
}
.div2-padding {
padding-top: 132px;
background-color: #ecc0fc;
}
h2.h2margin {
color: blue;
padding: 0!important;
margin: 0!important;
font-size: 18px;
}
h3 {
font-size: 18px;
color: green;
padding: 16px 0;
}
h2.h2padding {
color: red;
padding: 0!important;
margin: 0!important;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="h2margin">Here div 2 have margin top 132px and div 1 have margin bottom 32px.</h2>
<div class="div1-margin">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</div>
<div class="div2-margin">
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum portes factures. 
</div>
<h3>Total distance (space) above between div 2 and div 1 will be 132px? (margin used)</h3>
<h2 class="h2padding">Here div 2 have padding top 132px and div 1 have padding bottom 32px.</h2>
<div class="div1-padding">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</div>
<div class="div2-padding">
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum portes factures. 
</div>
<h3>Total distance (space) above between div 2 and div 1 will be 164px? (padding used)</h3>
```

Comment: MDN has a page on this 'collapsing margins' behavior (which is expected in certain circumstances) [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing There are ways round it, for example a CSS clear.

Comment: Read this articel https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/rules-of-margin-collapse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed margins can be ugly ... it's about the CSS specifications how browser have to handle with margins.

If two follwing elements have: `margin-bottom` and (the following) `margin-top` the margins not added every time. The most important rules in that case are:

1. If both values are positive is only taken the margin from the element with the higher margin.
2. If both values are negative is only taken the the marign from the element with lower (more negative) margin.
3. But head up: If one value is negative and the other one positive both margin are added (= negative value is substracted from the positive value) and the used margin **NOW** will be the result of both.

So, as you use only use positive values in your example: `margin-bottom` and `margin-top` are not added due to the specification. Using paddings are not affected by this rules so the result for the distance of the INNER elements is the result of the addition.

As of that in many `grid-frameworks` paddings are used to to setup the distances and not margins.

Here is a blog with ad good nearer explanation:
https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/